# How do I make a file in java.io.file?

Tags: java

So I was making a program called "TextCreator", and I ran into a problem, and it was that my program was not creating files. I wanted to make a file called "file.txt", and here's my code:

```
 String fileName = TxtName.getText();
  File file = new File("file.txt");
```

Because this was not working, I tried creating a file on my pc called "file.txt", and that did not work either. I am using java.io.file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a file and write to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it)

Comment: thank you! I guess I did not notice the "creating a text file" part of the question.

Comment: You may want to take a look at `java.nio` if you want to create a file nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing to actually 'create' the file.
Without any file operation nothing will actually happen in your file system, you simply created a java object describing a file by name.

E.g. to create an empty file you can call

```
file.createNewFile();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()

Or you can check the file exists (before trying to create a new one)

```
if(!file.exists) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

As [mentioned by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565754/how-do-i-make-a-file-in-java-io-file#comment117674200_66565754) I'd recommend looking into [java.nio.file.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) which offers a more modern API.